# Django query from multiple table base on FK

Tags: django

hi i am new in django coding
i have 3 tables(models) in my different Django app , i try to make a simple report in htmpl page , so need to retrive specific data for each item base on foreign key.

by below code i can accress machine stored table in Html page by
making a loop , but i want to fetch data from other table and filter them ,

```
{% for m in machines %}

    <h2>{{m.title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{}}</h3>.  
         //i** need to access the ordertitle field in tb_order base on machine id. ??**
    <p>{{ }}</p>.   
         // **access ordertitle in tb_order base on status field ??**
{%end for %}`
```

here is a view.py

```
def allmachinesLOGO(request):
    machines=Machine.objects.all()
    context ={'machines':machines}
    return render(request,'pline/machineslogos.html',context)
```

Models :

```
class tb_order(models.Model):     
    ordertitle= models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)        
    mould=models.ForeignKey(Mould, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)      
    status=models.CharField(choices=status_choices, default="0", max_length=20)        
    accept=models.BooleanField     
    machine=models.ForeignKey(Machine,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)     
    id =models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True)`

class Machine(models.Model):     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)     
    machine_model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)        
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True)     
    featured_image=models.ImageField(default="defaultmachine.webp", blank=True, null=True)         
    id=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)`
```

advice a solution
**access ordertitle in tb_order base on status field ??**
// i need to access the ordertitle field in tb_order base on machine id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the primary model, you can get the data associated with it from the secondary model. To do this, a special property (object) with the name secondary model_set is created in the primary model by default. In your case, for example: tb_order_set(lower case). Using related_name for the ForeignKey (in which case it will be whatever you write it without the _set prefix).

In the template, the outer loop loops through the rows of the model: Machine. The internal one, through tb_order_set.all, accesses the rows of the tb_order model. Although in my opinion it is better to do all calculations and comparisons in views, and in templates only display information.

Template file:

```
{% for m in machines %}
<p>{{ m.tb_order_set.all }}</p>
{% for r in m.tb_order_set.all %}
<p>{{ 'ordertitle' }} : {{ r.ordertitle }} {{ 'status' }} : {{ r.status }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To show by specific status:

```
{% for m in machines %}
<p>{{ m.tb_order_set.all }}</p>
{% for r in m.tb_order_set.all %}
{% if r.status  == '2' %}
<p>{{ 'ordertitle' }} : {{ r.ordertitle }} {{ 'status' }} : {{ r.status }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  I also try to use a filter to get orders by status but was not successful.   {% if m.tb_order_set.all.filter(status=='2') %}
                    <h4> working</h4> {% else %}
                      <h4>stop</h4>

Comment: updated answer. But, it's better to do all the filtering in the view. Templates are basically a display and their functionality is limited. At least I haven't seen any examples yet where a QuerySet can be filtered in a template.